# How to make matrix like text change effect in javascript?

Tags: javascript, text, random

I was trying to make this text change matrix movie like effect in JavaScript.The basic concept was that there is a div present in html and JavaScript take that div's inner text and manipulate it to create the continuously changing random text effect like in matrix movie. I am quite new to JavaScript, I am having hard time figuring out the logic behind the animation like the each steps, one step after another like what will happen next in whole animation process.

Anyways, I tried to make it on my own but as you can suspect i failed.

Here is my code :

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>

        var text = document.getElementById("text").innerText;
        var length_var = text.length;
        var possible = [];
        var possible_text ="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
        var counter = 0;
        var arr_text = [];

        var new_func = function(){
            arr_text[Math.floor(Math.random() * length_var)] = possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
            alert(arr_text);

        };

        var call_func = function(){

            for(var i=0; i<=possible_text.length; i++){
                possible[i] = possible_text.charAt(i);
            }

            for(var i=0; i<= length_var ; i++){
                arr_text[i] = text.charAt(i);
            }

            setInterval(new_func, 100);

        };

    </script>
</head>
<body onload="call_func()">

    <div id="text">
        Hello There!
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What I was planning to do can be seen on this page, as I was highly motivated to do this effect on my own.

Link : http://events.ccc.de/congress/2012/wiki/Main_Page

The header text of the page contains such animation.

Please Help

Comment: Probably more suited to code review.

Comment: ok, now i have posted there as well

Comment: @monk the link you've given has an expired SSL certificate.

Comment: you can remove the 's' from https. its a chaos communication congress latest event wiki page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This changes the string sequentially.

```
function main() {
    "use strict";
    var counter = 0, all = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    var $_inter = setInterval(function() {
        var text = document.getElementById("text");
        text.innerHTML = text.innerHTML.substring(0, counter) + all.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random()*all.length)) + text.innerHTML.substring(counter+1);
        counter = (counter+1)%text.innerHTML.length;
    }, 100);
}
window.onload = main;
```

Comment: How would I modify this so the changes are applied to multiple strings at different places?

Answer (score 3):

Here take a look at this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w5wsudd0/), as put together from [this resource](http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/matrix-rain-animation-html5-canvas-javascript). It is very fast and you can easily configure it.

Basically creates a blank canvas and renders the graphics. Here is the JS and HTML code that does that:

HTML:

```
<html style="background:black; width:100%; height:100%">
    <body style="background:black; width:100%; height:100%">
        <canvas id="c" style="display: block;"></canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var c = document.getElementById("c");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

//making the canvas full screen
c.height = window.innerHeight;
c.width = window.innerWidth;

//chinese characters - taken from the unicode charset
var chinese = "田由甲申甴电甶男甸甹町画甼甽甾甿畀畁畂畃畄畅畆畇畈畉畊畋界畍畎畏畐畑";
//converting the string into an array of single characters
chinese = chinese.split("");

var font_size = 10;
var columns = c.width/font_size; //number of columns for the rain
//an array of drops - one per column
var drops = [];
//x below is the x coordinate
//1 = y co-ordinate of the drop(same for every drop initially)
for(var x = 0; x < columns; x++)
    drops[x] = 1; 

//drawing the characters
function draw()
{
    //Black BG for the canvas
    //translucent BG to show trail
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

    ctx.fillStyle = "#0F0"; //green text
    ctx.font = font_size + "px arial";
    //looping over drops
    for(var i = 0; i < drops.length; i++)
    {
        //a random chinese character to print
        var text = chinese[Math.floor(Math.random()*chinese.length)];
        //x = i*font_size, y = value of drops[i]*font_size
        ctx.fillText(text, i*font_size, drops[i]*font_size);

        //sending the drop back to the top randomly after it has crossed the screen
        //adding a randomness to the reset to make the drops scattered on the Y axis
        if(drops[i]*font_size > c.height && Math.random() > 0.975)
            drops[i] = 0;

        //incrementing Y coordinate
        drops[i]++;
    }
}

setInterval(draw, 33);
```

Comment: Ah ok my problem, I will update my answer, thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 2):

Try this-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function randString(len) {
            "use strict";
               var i, out="", all ="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
                for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    out += all.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random()*all.length));
                }
            return out;
        }
        function main() {
            "use strict";
            var $_inter = setInterval(function() {
                var text = document.getElementById("text");
                text.innerHTML = randString(text.innerHTML.length);
            }, 100);
        }
        window.onload = main;
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="text">Hello World!</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thankyou, one question though, why to use strict mode why not normally?

Comment: @monk I like to write [JSLINT](http://jslint.com) proof code. It's just your choice.

Comment: can you please help me change the texts, sequentially like first, the middle character then the first or the second and then the third like that

Comment: @Sann—so why is "use strict" only used in function context and not global? Why use CDATA in an HTML document?

Comment: @RobG I strictly adhere to jslint. According to that, `"use strict"` shouldn't be global. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode

Comment: @RobG for `CDATA` read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/CDATASection)...

Comment: @Sann CDATA in html really isn't needed at this point, unless you're trying to guarantee that your pages validate in html4.01-strict or xhtml...  ...which is pointless, if you're using the `html` doctype.  Doing things like using JS to comment CDATA which comments html-comments has been pointless since Netscape Navigator died.

Comment: @Norguard yeah you're right... my bad. `CDATA` ain't required here.

Answer (score 1):

The crux of the program that's on the site (which is really, really ugly) involves creating an array of "haXX0r-like" characters, and then injecting them and removing them from the text.

They also speed up and slow down their process, and bounce between doing an addition pass and a removal pass, from what I saw on my quick read-through.

The downside of their code are that it's all a bunch of loops slopped together, with a bunch of "if"s to contain two or three loops, one after the other...  ...and then they add "mode-switching" to that, where they say "if we're in mode-1 add stuff and do it quickly, and if we're in mode-2, remove stuff and lower the speed and if we're in this submode of either mode, set the speed accordingly, and if the speed is greater than this or less than that, and we're in this mode, then stop what we're doing, wait 5 seconds and call it again"...

...not pretty.

But they're starting with a quote, finding a random spot in the string, and then replacing the character at that spot with the character, plus the new "<", "?", "{", etc...

And speeding up and slowing down, as they add and remove the randomly-chosen character-type.

Comment: how can you change the character at particular position while storing it in an array and then replacing the same position character in web screen too?

Comment: i tried doing that using charAT but says left hand side assignment or something like that error.. i was doing like this

string.charAt(i) = randompost.charAt(i)

Comment: @monk it was giving you a "left-hand side" error because `.charAt()` returns the letter at that position. If `string.charAt(3) === "a";` then you were basically saying `"a" = "{";` and the computer disagreed with you.  `var i = random(), start = string.slice(0, i), end = string.slice(i); string = start + characters(random()) + end;` would be a quick and dirty way to modify the value of `string` to inject something between letters that are supposed to be there.

Comment: @monk PS: `random()` doesn't actually exit, you'll have to make it, or use `Math.floor(Math.random() * string.length)`.  Putting that out there, just in case dealing with random numbers in JS is new to you.

Answer (score 1):

Elegant snippet

```js
canvas = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('canvas'))
screen = window.screen;
width = canvas.width = screen.width;
height = canvas.height = screen.height;
p = Array(255).join(1).split('');
context = canvas.getContext('2d');

setInterval(function(){
    context.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.05)';
    context.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
    context.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,255,0,1)';
    p = p.map(function(v,i){
        r = Math.random();
        context.fillText(String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(2720 + r * 33)),i*10,v);
        v += 10; 
        return v > 768 + r * 1e4 ? 0 : v
    })
}, 33)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want something that will randomise a string and slowly replace each character with the original, here's something that may suit. The replacement order is random too, so the string is replaced out of order but ends up with the original string.

A fancier solution is to give each letter its own timer with a different lag so they run at different speeds, and for different lengths of time. But that might suck some serious system resources for a big string.

```
function Randomiser(el, count, delay) {
  this.element = el;
  this.originalText = el.textContent || el.innerText || '';
  this.places = [];
  this.currentText = [];
  this.count = count || 3;   // iterations before fixing a character
  this.delay = delay || 100; // milliseconds between updates
  this.iteration = 0;
  this.startTime = new Date();

  var i = this.originalText.length;

  while (i--) {
    this.places[i] = [i];
  }
}

Randomiser.prototype.randomise = function() {
  var charSet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
  var i = this.places.length;

  while (i--) {
    this.currentText[this.places[i]] = charSet.charAt((Math.random() * charSet.length) | 0);
  }
  this.iteration += 1;
}

Randomiser.prototype.setContent = function() {
  var t = this.currentText.join('');

  if (typeof this.element.textContent == 'string') {
    this.element.textContent = t;
  } else {
    this.element.innerText = t;
  }
}

Randomiser.prototype.run = function() {
  var n;
  var temp = [];

  // If first run, randomise to initiate
  if (!this.iteration) {
    this.randomise();
  }

  // If there are places left
  if (this.places.length) {

    // If reached count, randomly remove one place and set its character
    // to the original value
    if (!(this.iteration % this.count)) {
      n = this.places.splice((Math.random() * this.places.length|0), 1)[0];
      this.currentText[n] = this.originalText.charAt(n);
    }

    // Randomise the string and call itself
    this.randomise(); 
    this.setContent();
    var randomiser = this;
    setTimeout(function(){randomiser.run();}, this.delay); 
  }
  // If no places left, end
}

// Kick it off
var r = new Randomiser(document.getElementById('text'), 5, 200);
r.run();
```

The above uses classic prototype inheritance, it could use a closure for the same thing. Also all those prototype functions could be put in a single object that is assigned to Randomiser.prototype.